# Date values to invariant strings

Tags: .net, date

I have a string containing a date in german format (dd.MM.yyyy), so the date separator is a dot.

My operation system is german, so the default culture is german with the default date format like shown above.

I need to convert this date string to an invariant date string (yyyy/MM/dd).

And here are my problems:

If I'm doing the obvious like

```
Convert.ToDateTime(value, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"))
       .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

I get the string in invariant culture, but it contains the unwanted time portion as well, so I get for instance "2020/11/09 00:00:00".

So I thought to myself, I'll tell .NET, that I just want the `ShortDataPattern` like

```
Convert.ToDateTime(value, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"))
       .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DataTimeFormats.ShortDatePattern)
```

But since `ShortDatePattern` of the invariant culture is `yyyy/MM/dd` and I'm on a german computer, where the date separator is a dot, I get "2020.11.09".

The only other ways I can think of are kind of hacky, like using the first way and cutting the time portion by string operations. Or instead of using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DataTimeFormats.ShortDatePattern` using `yyyy\/MM\/dd` (masking the slashes to be used as literals).

Are there any other ways that are not kind of hacky to get a date string without the time in invariant format, regardless of the culture of the computer I'm on?

Comment: Just do `value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. Note that that is *not* the native format of the invariant culture; that would be `value.ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` and gives `11/09/2020` (dd/MM/yyyy). Invariant != global standard, if you want ISO 8601 dates, I'd recommend sticking with `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: Thank you for the push in the right direction. I want to avoid giving any custom formatting information, so I go with `Convert.ToDateTime(value, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: ... or `yyyyMMdd` (which is the other variant of ISO8601)

Comment: I'm aware of the ISO formats, but our client expects strings with invariant values, so I have to stick with these.

Comment: Technically `"d"` is not custom formatting, it's one of the [standard formatting strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#date-formats). It has exactly the same effect as using `ShortDatePattern` explicitly, but it's, well, shorter. (And also can't accidentally be combined with the "wrong" culture.)